# What is the best way to make all of the functions for a class run in a separate thread with PyQt5?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I have a worker class that handles some simple functionality to interface with Meta's Segment Anything Model. I would like to be able to call each of the functions in this class such that they execute in a separate thread when called without spawning a new thread each time.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from segment_anything import SamPredictor, sam_model_registry
import config


class SAM_worker(QObject):
    ready = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, cuda, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.cuda = cuda
        
    def config_model(self, img):
        self.sam = sam_model_registry[config.MODEL_TYPE](config.CHECK_POINT)
        if self.cuda: self.sam.to(device='cuda')

        self.predictor = SamPredictor(self.sam)
        self.set_image(img)
        self.ready.emit()
        
    def set_image(self, img):
        self.predictor.set_image(img, 'BGR')
        
    def predict(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.predictor.predict(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know that you can move a QObject to a QThread by calling `.moveToThread()`, but calling these functions directly after doing this (rather than using them as pyqtSlot's) still blocks the main thread. Would it be best here just to subclass QThread instead?

Comment: To make this happen automatically for all methods I think you'd have to use a metaclass. It might be simpler to write a decorator that you use with selected methods that should be in the thread.

Comment: Do not call methods directly - always use signals to communicate with worker threads, as this will ensure the slots are invoked asynchronously. One way to do this is to create a custom signal that sends the name and arguments of the worker method you want to invoke, and then call it using `getattr(self, method)(*args)`; another (less Pythonic) approach is to use [QMetaObject.invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod). To make these solutions work, you should use `moveToThread` rather thab subclassing `QThread` as they both require a local event-loop.